# How do I add the currency symbol in a view, to a value pulled from a model?

Tags: angularjs

I need to precede a value pulled from JSON with '$'. How do I do this?

I want

```
<span ng-model="item.value"></span>
```

to render $12.34, given that in the model the value of item.value = 12.34

Comment: What do you intend ng-model to do on a span? Do you understand what ng-model is?

Comment: @JBNizet ahh. You guided me to the answer. Thanks so much. I am new, and was confused as to the difference between ng-model and ng-bind. I'll post my answer and credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @JBNizet I found the answer! I posted below, in case this may help someone else in the future.

```
<span ng-bind="item.value | currency:USD$:2"></span>
```

I had to change 'ng-model' to 'ng-bind' and add the currency filter.
For other newbies struggling with this - ng-model is two-way data binding, used when you user will be making changes to the data (via a form input for example). ng-bind is one-way data binding for pulling data, data that won't be changed, from the model.

Filters cannot be applied to ng-model; you instead create a formatter.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span>{{item.value | currency }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<span>{{item.value | currency}}</span>
```

Also check [How to Format a String Using AngularJS “currency” Filter?](http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/format-text-using-angularjs-currency-filter.htm)

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4s5s386/10/)**